# I need to modify the field display on my form?.. Ruby on Rails... RoR...

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is currently what the form looks like in _form:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :time_at_address %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :time_at_address %>
</div>
```

However, the label I display to the end user I would like to say: "Please enter time at current address."

How do I change what is displayed? I don't care to change my model, controller, or table..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check the documentation for label method: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-label

Comment: Helpful documentation... thanks Octopus-Paul.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, i hope it works;

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :time_at_address, "Please enter time at current address." %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :time_at_address %>
</div>
```

Comment: Phew! Thanks Acacia that worked correctly... I would of had a lot of rework to do if it hadn't...... Cheers!

Comment: Great, then you can accept it an answer to stop the agony for other people.